The default covariance structure implicitly assumed in the brms formula
Background: The brms official page provides the following example code to illustrate the usage of the package:
fit1 <- brm(count ~ zAge + zBase * Trt + (1|patient),
            data = epilepsy, family = poisson())

This formula defines a Poisson mixed-effect regression model on a set of count data epilepsy, with a group-level random intercept (1|patient). However, the specific covariance structure implicitly assumed in this model definition is not immediately clear.
Problem: What kind of covariance structure is assumed in the code above?
My Guess: Based upon the documentation for the gr() function, I believe that:

For the same patient, the residual errors of different visits are assumed to be independent.
Between different patients, the random intercepts are assumed to be correlated.

Consequently, the covariance matrix of the residual errors will have non-zero diagonal components, and non-zero non-diagonal components only if the patient numbers are different. Within the same patient, there will be no correlation between different visits, leading to zero off-diagonal components.
I would appreciate any hints or corrections you can provide. Thanks in advance.

Greetings and welcome to CV! What is the actual question you have here? It seems you have some implicit questions here based off what you have listed for the gr() and brm() functions, but its not clear what you are trying to ask.

Perhaps it would help to simplify the question. The Poisson model, fit1, has no gr() term so that seems irrelevant. Do you want to understand how {brms} models the (1 | patient) term?

@dipetkov Thank you for helping me clarify my point. Regarding the gr() function, I've just realized that I assumed gr()  would be called as soon as a brmsformula object is instantiated.

@ShawnHemelstrand Yes, exactly! Let me edit my question based on your advice.

I'm afraid the new version is not too abstract. As 'residual error', I mean the sum of the two error terms: the population-level error and the group-level error.

To analyse the covariance structure assumed in the model specified by the brm() function from the brms package, let's break down the formula and its components:
fit1 <- brm(count ~ zAge + zBase * Trt + (1|patient),
            data = epilepsy, family = poisson())

This specifies a Poisson mixed-effects regression model. Here's how the elements contribute to the assumed covariance structure:
Components of the Model

Fixed Effects: zAge, zBase, and Trt where zBase * Trt indicates an interaction between the baseline and the treatment.

Random Effects: (1|patient) signifies a random intercept for each patient. This accounts for variability in counts that is not explained by the observed variables (zAge, zBase, and Trt).


Covariance Structure
1. Within-Patient Covariance:

The model (1|patient) introduces a random intercept for each patient, which means that there is an additional level of variation specific to each patient that is consistent across all measurements for that patient.

The residual errors for each count measurement within the same patient are assumed to be independent conditional on this patient-specific random intercept. Therefore, the covariance of residual errors within the same patient, after accounting for the random intercept, is zero. Thus, there are no off-diagonal components in the residual covariance matrix for observations from the same patient.


2. Between-Patient Covariance:

The random intercepts for different patients are assumed to be normally distributed with a mean of zero and some variance $\omega^2$. This variance component captures the variability in epilepsy count levels from patient to patient, beyond what is explained by the fixed effects.

The covariance between the random intercepts of different patients is assumed to be zero, as each random intercept is independent of the others. This assumption leads to no covariance (zero off-diagonal elements) between measurements from different patients.


Summary of Your Guess

You're correct that the residual errors for different visits within the same patient are assumed independent. This is a fundamental assumption in many mixed-effects models where only random intercepts are considered.

The random intercepts between different patients are not correlated; they are independent. Thus, the covariance matrix of the random intercepts would have zero off-diagonal components between different patients. The non-zero components you mentioned are actually the variance of the intercepts across patients, not covariance between different patients.


Thus, the entire covariance structure for the model described in the brm() function is such that:

There is no correlation between residuals across different visits within the same patient or between different patients.
The variance within patients (random intercept variance) captures patient-specific variability in the response, independent across patients.

Of course, this does not mean that the given model is the correct one. For repeated measures on patients in it natural to expect serial correlation among observations on the same patient. This model does not account for that.

Thank you so much for your insightful answer! I understand you are busy, but I would truly appreciate if you had time to address one follow-up question. In the documentation, it says 'By default, group-level terms will be modelled as correlated.' (The function gr() is called internally.)

Should I interpret this sentence to mean that random intercepts have already accounted for the correlation, and therefore, the residual errors are (assumed to be) independent?

You are very welcome. I’m glad that it helped. Please post a new question for your follow-on and then ping me here on this thread and I will take a look
